# Servlet 3.0 logout doesn't work

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, servlet-3.0

I've got a problem with the authentication features of Servlet 3.0:

With this code in a Servlet v3:

```
log.info(""+request.getUserPrincipal());
log.info(""+request.getAuthType());
log.info("===^===");
request.logout() ;
log.info(""+request.getUserPrincipal());
log.info(""+request.getAuthType());
request.authenticate(response) ;
log.info("===v===");
log.info(""+request.getUserPrincipal());
log.info(""+request.getAuthType());
```

I would *always* expect to see the Username/login windows, because of the `logout()` function. Instead, it seems to be a 'cache' mechanism which repopulate the credential and cancel my logout ...

> Admin
>
> BASIC
>
> ===^===
>
> null
>
> null
>
> ===v===
>
> Admin
>
> BASIC

Is it a problem with my firefox, or something I'm missing in the Servlet code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would always expect to see the Username/login windows, because of the [`logout()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#logout%28%29) function. Instead, it seems to be a 'cache' mechanism which repopulate the credential and cancel my logout ...

That's the way HTTP BASIC AUTH was designed, it allows all authenticate state to be kept in the client. In other words, its **impossible** to logout with basic/digest authentication, the server cannot stop a client from caching and resending a BASIC auth authenticator on subsequent requests to the server.

My suggestion is to use form based authentication and the [`login`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method of [`HTTPServletRequest`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html).

#### References

- [New Security Features in Glassfish v3 (Java EE 6) - Part II](http://blogs.oracle.com/nithya/entry/new_security_features_in_glassfish1)
- [New Security Features in Glassfish v3 (Java EE 6) - Part III](http://blogs.oracle.com/nithya/entry/new_security_features_in_glassfish2)
- [Easiest and most portable way to authenticate programatically](http://forums.java.net/jive/message.jspa?messageID=386382)
- [How to log users out from Glassfish server - need help from SUN](http://forums.java.net/jive/message.jspa?messageID=392823)

Comment: the form based authentication seems to work correctly, although the BASIC popup box was quite conveniant, I guess I'm not the only one who tried to use it this way!

Comment: @Pascal Thivent all links are broken

Answer (score 1):

It's neither. Once logged in, the browser will always pass your user id and password to the url. Until you restart your browser. As far as I know each browser does that. And as far as I know there's currently no way to tell the browser to forget about the credentials.

However, you'll see your session will be different once you logged out. The usual solution is to add a variable of some kind to the session. Say "loggedin". If this variable is missing you know the user has to log in first and you'll redirect to say login.jsp. And once the user passed this jsp you set this variable again.

Using filters you can enforce this system-wide.

Comment: How would such a login.jsp look like? I want the user of my web application to be able to login with a different account using basic authetication.